# Non-hacky way to keep Python scripts in sub-directory?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a file structure like this:

```
a.py
b.py
c.py
scripts:
  --script1.py
  --script2.py
```

I want the scripts to be able to import files from the parent directory.
What would be the best way to do this?

Ideally, I'd avoid using PYTHONPATH hacks.

Comment: Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4383597/16569581

Comment: I'm trying to avoid modifying the python path. If this means I need to re-organize my code, then so be it

Comment: If you aren't installing your modules to a known directory on the Python search path, you are going to have to use "PYTHONPATH hacks".

Comment: That said, simply putting your scripts in the top-level directory and the modules in a subdirectory will simplify matters, because the directory containing the script is automatically added to the Python search path.

Comment: installing something (& thus mutating my local python installation) just to run a script gives me a bad taste; but maybe if that's the only way I'll have to just suck it up @chepner

Comment: @Foobar That's what virtual environments are for.

Answer (score 0):

I would use:

```
import sys

sys.path.insert(0, full/path/to/import/folder)

import a, b, c
```

My IDE does not detect the module and calls it an error, but when I run the code, it works. Hopefully, it works for you too! Also, try searching stuff up like this on google, this is one of the most popular ways.